# Review of a search methodology: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm considering formulating a question about a proposed complex search I'm going to undertake, and the assumptions on which it's based, and seeking feedback on (a) flaws in the assumptions (b) flaws in the search process (c) steps I can take to mitigate those flaws.

Is this on-topic, or is it too close to asking for opinions?

---

Edited to add: I'm splitting the question into at least two parts, to make it manageable The first (on assumptions) is: [Does the available evidence support these assumptions?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12655/104)

Comment: I broadly agree with @PolyGeo's answer below. I think this proposal can be kept on-topic and, together with answers, could form a case study that would help other researchers in a similar situation.

Comment: I think it is a great question.  I think it would be good to have each assumption asked about in its own Q&A but I'm happy to see it left as one question rather than losing it.

Comment: @andyW I was hopeful it would make a good case study, prompting researchers to examine their own assumptions more closely.

Answer (score 1):

If we were getting 10 questions a day every day then I might think we need to be stricter, and without seeing the question it is hard to be certain whether or not it is on-topic.

Consequently, I think you should ask it, and the worst scenario is that the community votes it to be closed as off-topic.  I think it is far more likely that any opinion-seeking aspects can be re-worded to bring it more on-topic if we have any concerns that it may be setting a bad example.

After it has been asked, it can also be linked back into your question, so that we have a concrete example for any future discussion here.

Comment: Having started to write the question, it's very long, so I may split it into two questions: one asking about the assumptions and one asking about the search/elimination process.  I'll test the water with the assumptions question first.